# Which component should be used for time selector in Kivy

Tags: kivy

In my app settings, i want user can select time from `00h 00m` to `12h 00m`. I dont want user to enter it to textbox. How should i implement it. Should i use 2 separate sliders for hours and minutes, or should i use 2 spinners or is their any other component which i am missing.

Can i turm this spinner to circular spinner somehow to show just 3 options at a time:

```
Spinner:
    size_hint_x:.5
    text: '00'
    values: ('00', '01', '02', '03','04', '05', '06', '07','08', '09', '10', '11','12')
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [KivyGarden](https://github.com/kivy-garden), you can find pretty flowers there ;) The wheel installation has already garden in it, but you can check if you have it in your python via `pip list`.

There is actually something *[flat](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.datetimepicker)* you want and also something *[circular](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.circulardatetimepicker)*. If you have garden installed, there are some import *[instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.garden.html)*, but you can also download the package and place it in your app folder.